# Difference between inconclusive and non-conclusive (nonconclusive)

Tags: differences, adjectives

Is there any difference in usage between *inconclusive* and *non-conclusive (nonconclusive)*?

[inconclusive](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=inconclusive) is more popular in research compared to [non-conclusive](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=non-conclusive), using PubMed search, 20,872 and 260 respectively. ([nonconclusive](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=nonconclusive) gives 117 hits).

[Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/inconclusive) doesn't list them as synonyms.

Comment: I have never come across *non-conclusive*, and it isn't listed in the popular dictionaries. I think that your hit counts say it all.

Comment: @Mick same here, never seen *non-conclusive* until recently, and looks like it is used "rarely" in research papers, hence the question.

Comment: I think that one difference is that "inconclusive" can have a slightly pejorative flavor in some contexts, whereas "non-conclusive" would avoid that.

Comment: @HotLicks that is good point, also thanks, learned a new word: [pejorative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pejorative).

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm not convinced.  Can you present something persuasive?

Comment: "Inconclusive" to me means that the jury is still out -- we don't have enough evidence to draw a conclusion.  "Non-conclusive" expresses a judgment of the value of the evidence or the argument.  If I reject a piece of evidence, or an argument, in other words, if I want to say that it is not sufficient to lead to a particular conclusion, then I could say that it is "non-conclusive."  But I've never said that.  I say things like "the argument doesn't hold water" or "is not persuasive" or "the evidence cited does not support the proposed conclusion," etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Inconclusive** - According to Merriam Webster, [Inconclusive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconclusive) means:

- leading to no conclusion or definite result

Neither **Merriam Webster** nor **Oxford Advanced Learners** list **non-conclusive** (or **nonconclusive**) as a word. So it's most likely that non-conclusive isn't a regular English word (I have never heard of it), rather it is a specialized word used in particular academic or professional disciplines.

From a quick google search I can see, most of the hits that **non-conclusive** got was from poorly written articles, in many cases from foreign writers. So, even if some people used it as a hyphenated compound word to express the same meaning as **inconclusive**, it is redundant (and a bit in poor taste.)

**Non-conclusive** does have some specialized usage as I mentioned. There is a **Non-conclusive** verb in the progressive tenses. The term was most likely first used by A.S Hornby in his articles and papers in the 1940's and 1950's. These are now generally known as *Stative Verbs.* [Non-conclusive Verb [Journal link]](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00138389108598743?journalCode=nest20)

There is also **Non-conclusive Judgment** in law.  [Law-Dictionary](http://thelawdictionary.org/nonconclusive-judgment/)

These are the only few usage that I came across. There might be more specialized used in particular fields. But if I wanted to express something that *"is leading to no conclusion/definite result"* I would stick to **inconclusive**.

Comment: But the words don't mean the same thing. "Inconclusve" means the result of a question or investigation did not yield a conclusive result, whereas "Nonconclusive" means an event or discussion did not lead to a conclusion and is still open-ended. It's a nuanced difference but definitely a real difference.

Comment: @BenLee, is that a real difference? Saying that a particular argument is inconclusive, always leaves it open that some other argument for the same conclusion will be found in the future and that it will be conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford on-line dictionary gives two principle meanings of "conclusive". These are

> the end or finish of an event, process, or text

and

> a judgement or decision reached by reasoning.

Broadly, inconclusive is commonly used in opposition  to the second meaning. We say that the evidence was inconclusive, meaning that it was insufficient to allow a definite judgement to be made.  The meeting was inconclusive if no decision could be made.

Non-conclusive is in opposition to the second meaning. Something is non-conclusive if it is not the end of the matter.

As Rio1210 has identified  non-conclusive is used in law regarding a judgement that is subject to appeal. The decision of the court is non-conclusive because it is not the end of the matter, or not necessarily the end of the matter.

The meeting came to a decision, but it is non-conclusive because it still has to go to the board.

Comment: So, is there a difference in meaning between the two or not? What you say about them leaves an impression that their meanings are the same, but you don't say so explicitly.